# JavaScript is not working on Swedish letters

Tags: javascript, encoding

My javascript code for filtering is not working on Swedish letters *å ä ö*

```
<input name='tablefilter' type='checkbox' value='Linköping' id='tablefilter1' checked/>
<label for='tablefilter1'>Linköping</label>
<input name='tablefilter' type='checkbox' value='Mjölby' id='tablefilter2' checked/>
<label for='tablefilter2'>Mjölby</label>
<input name='tablefilter' type='checkbox' value='Norrköping' id='tablefilter3' checked/>
<label for='tablefilter3'>Norrköping</label>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='tablebody'>
    <tr>
      <td>Linköping</td>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>First</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mjölby</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Norrköping</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Third</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

js

```
/* Demo filtering table using checkboxes. Filters against first td value */

/* Set 'ready' handler' */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initFunc);

/* When document ready, set click handlers for the filter boxes */
function initFunc(event) {
  var filters = document.getElementsByName('tablefilter');
  for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
    filters[i].addEventListener('click', buildAndExecFilter);
  }
}

/*
    This function gets called when clicking on table filter checkboxes.
    It builds a list of selected values and then filters the table based on that
*/
function buildAndExecFilter() {
  var show = [];
  var filters = document.getElementsByName('tablefilter');
  for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
    if (filters[i].checked) {
      show.push(filters[i].value);
    }
  }
  execFilter(show); // Filter based on selected values
}

function execFilter(show) {
  /* For all rows of table, see if td 0 contains a selected value to filter */
  var rows = document.getElementById('tablebody').getElementsByTagName('tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var display = ""; // Default to display
    // If it is not found in the selected filter values, don't show it
    if (show.indexOf(rows[i].children[0].textContent) === -1) {
      display = "none";
    }
    // Update the display accordingly
    rows[i].style.display = display;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Lm7pytt/4/

It works on jsfiddle, but it's not working on my visual studio. The problem is **not** that it can't display Swedish letters, because it can.

The problem is that the JavaScript is not working on Swedish letters.

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: How can a letter **not work**. It's not as if it was a motorcycle... :-?

Comment: @Álvaro Letters are lazy bastards. Always hanging 'round the bar at noon, not getting a job... – Seriously though, we need to know what "not working" means if you want help, OP.

Comment: @deceze I already told you that it's the JavaScript that's not working. Was I unclear?

Comment: I have tried creating this through Visual Studio and have had no problems with it working as designed - I would suspect you have some kind of encoding issue - Go to FILE > Advanced Save Options in Visual Studio and check the encoding option set here as well as Brandon's suggestion in the answers below

Comment: My bike *doesn't work* either, will you fix it for me? … No no, it still has wheels and there's air in the tires, that's not the problem. It's just *not working*. … You get what the problem with this kind of "error description" is yet?

Comment: @deceze My JavaScript does not recognize Swedish letters, that is the problem. I don't know more than that.

Answer (score 2):

you might try adding to the top of the head tag

> < meta charset="utf-8" />

Answer (score 0):

This could fail at several points but it is most likely failing on the comparison due to an encoding issue, so I would suggest using the debugger to breakpoint the JavaScript before this line:

```
if (show.indexOf(rows[i].children[0].textContent) === -1) {
     display = "none";
}
```

Check what is contained within `textContent`, try doing a comparison in your Immediate Window, e.g. `rows[i].children[0].textContent === "Linköping"`. If you find this coming back false, this will likely confirm it.

Go to FILE > Advanced Save Options in Visual Studio and check the encoding option set here - I am using "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001" and my code includes the meta code as seen in Brandon's suggestion in the answers below. With these set, it is running as intended, for me.